# Node JS | Heroku | MongoDB Atlas | How do I make sure only my app can access my backend?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

I've built my backend using MongoDB Atlas, Express, and Node JS and deployed it to Heroku. Using Postman, the app is operating properly so far (users are getting added and I'm receiving the json web token correctly).

But I'm thinking that this might not be correct because it seems like anyone with access to my Heroku URL and routes can easily create a new user, receive the json web token, and basically operate their entire app using my backend.

**My questions are:**

1. Am I missing something huge about how I've built my backend?
2. How do I go about securing my backend so that only my apps can access the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Passportjs](http://www.passportjs.org/) to protect your routes, passport will be your middleman between person accessing the back-end and your actual back-end.

You can give access to the routes if a valid JWT is passed ([JWT strategy](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/)) otherwise it will throw 401 (Unauthorized).

There are 400+ strategies available, I will recommend JWT one because you are already generating JWT.

Protecting backed is integral part because most of scripts can disable security on front-end leaving apps vulnerable to attacks.

Comment: Apologies, I'm still new to coding and may not have understood your suggestion. I've implemented JWT for authentication on routes. However, if a random person went into Postman, she could still submit a username and password to the sign-up route and receive a JWT and go through the manual process on each route submitting the JWT in the header and recreating each request. So I guess what I'm missing is if there is a way to say "this is my app making this request not some random person using postman".